# Using css blend mode on DOM element above the element with the background image

Tags: css

Was curious if anyone knew how to apply a background-color using the new css property background-blend-mode on an element (such as a header) that sits higher(z-index) than the element that has the background image that needs to be blended with?

I see how you can apply a background image, a background color, and a background blend mode to the same element but I would think something like this would work for a small sliver of the page as well. I have a background image for my site but only want a portion of the header to blend a different color with that background...

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: [Check it out](https://medium.com/web-design-technique/css-blend-modes-could-be-the-next-big-thing-in-web-design-6b51bf53743a) but most of the browsers do not support `background-blend-mode` yet..

Answer (score 0):

After a little more digging, I've discovered that the `mix-blend-mode` will accomplish what I'm looking for. It appears that `background-blend-mode` and `mix-blend-mode` are right on the cusp of being released into the main builds of Chrome and Firefox.

One thing I want to note is that the blend mode won't necessary work through multiple layers depending on your background settings of the layers in between what you want blended. You may have to add your `mix-blend-mode` to one or more layers in between.