# Blending 2 elements background colors using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, photoshop

I need to blend the background colors of 2 elements using CSS
I have been fiddling around with the `background-blend-mode:multiply` but that works only when I have the 2 colors in the same element.

I need to achieve something like this -

---

[image]

I have been searching a lot but haven't been able to figure it out.
Most helpful resource I found was [New blending features in CSS](https://web.archive.org/web/20170825054500/http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2012/07/17/new-blending-features-in-css/) which shows how to do it using Canvas.
Is it possible to do the same thing using CSS?

**EDIT**

---

The circles above were just an example to show what I needed. As I mentioned, I was looking for blending colors for 2 different elements. I have created a fiddle for my actual shapes that I need to blend. 
http://jsfiddle.net/fmgfsr4o/2/

Comment: I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986063/using-css-blend-mode-on-dom-element-above-the-element-with-the-background-image) that might help.

Comment: did you try using multiple background on the same element ? something like this: first background is a red circle on the left, second one is a green circle on the right. I think you can draw it in pure CSS, maybe with some gradients or similar. Also you can try to play with CSS pseudo elements (`:after` and `:before`)

Comment: Basically...No. Blend modes are not yet available in CSS and there is no CSS alternative. You **might** be able to do something in JS though.

Comment: @Paulie_D CSS blend modes seems available in latest Firefox, Chrome and Opera, and even in Chrome for Android, check it out: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode

Comment: It's a Candidate Recommendation at the moment so it's not really something we should be using in production just yet.

Comment: @pomeh Actually, I have more complex shapes than a circle so it becomes impossible to create using just gradients. Something like this -http://jsfiddle.net/fmgfsr4o/2/

Comment: @Paulie_D yes you're right. Thanks for pointing that out. KshitizShankar that was just an idea, which was almost correct since I have done it (see my answer below). But with such a shape it's another level of complexity for sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine CSS multiple background with radial-gradients to achieve this effect:

CSS

```
div {
  /* adjust the width of the container to adjust circle's
     overlap size and shape */
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  /* for debug purpose only */
  border: solid blue 1px;

  background:
    /* draw the red circle */
    radial-gradient(red 0%, red 70%, transparent 70%, transparent 100%) 0 0,
    /* draw the green circle */
    radial-gradient(green 0%, green 70%, transparent 70%, transparent 100%) 0 0;
    /* the red on the left, the green on the right */
  background-position: top left, top right;

  /* you can make then bigger or smaller */
  /* but you have to change width size above too */
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  /* You want both circles to appears once only */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  /* you can try with other values too */
  /* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode */
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

HTML

```
<div></div>
```

I have done a JSFiddle for you to try: http://jsfiddle.net/pomeh/07nLpwwj/

This is the result I get using Firefox 31:

[image: circles]

Even if the browser support seems "correct" (see here http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode), please note that the `background-blend-mode` property has the Candidate Recommendation status for now, so be careful when using it (thanks to @Paulie_D for pointing that out).

Comment: As I mentioned, I need to merge the background color of "2 elements" circles was just an example, my shapes are bit more complex and require to be created using different HTML elements (For eg. consider 2 diamond shapes that are overlapping). Is it possible to do that with CSS?

Comment: @KshitizShankar I'm not sure it's possible, `background-blend-mode` works on one element only. Please update your question and add details on what you need **exactly**: my answer seems to correspond to your question, but your question doesn't correspond to what you really need, so you will never find an useful answer that way.

Comment: I have edited the question and attached a fiddle for my actual shapes that I need to blend. I am not sure if I can achieve it using CSS though..

Comment: I'm not sure either :/ The demo in your fiddle uses pseudo elements `:after` and `:before` but those are sort of considered as different elements o you can't use blend mode across them. Maybe it could work if the shapes were in a image and you use `background-image: url(firstShape), url(secondShape)`, but it requires the use of external images and it may not be what you want :/

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's a no go with CSS. May be in future!
Thanks a lot for all the help though. I am going to stick with images and then blend them using CSS I think..

Comment: Yeah sure.. will do. I am hoping mix-blend-mode will be available in the browsers in near future. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this pure CSS3, although you will need to figure out how to position the circles.

```
html {
height: 100%;
background:
    repeating-radial-gradient(
        circle,
        transparent,
        transparent 3.5em,
        tomato 1em,
        tomato 4.5em
    ),
    repeating-radial-gradient(
        circle,
        transparent,
        transparent 3.5em,
        dodgerblue 3.5em,
        dodgerblue 4.5em
    );

background-blend-mode: multiply;
background-size: 10em 10em;
background-position:
    0 0,
    5em 5em,
    10em 5em;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcivorni/r490euen/2/)

Comment: I am looking for an answer to do it with CSS. I already know I can achieve it using JS and Canvas

Comment: DyspraxicDesigner your edit was a too radical change to your response, it changes totally the content of your response (from a JavaScript solution to a CSS one). In the future please pay attention to that, because now @KshitizShankar have to reconsider your response. If you really want to make a such radical change, please post a new answer and then delete the first one. Thanks.